Did Jesus personally perform 33, 35, or 37 recorded miracles before his resurrection in the Gospels?
How many recorded miracles did Jesus perform  in the Gospels? The first list claims there were 37, the next list claims 35, and the last list claims 33 miracles.
With certainty, are there 33, 35, or 37 pre-resurrection miracles recorded in the Gospels?


Why ask this here.  What list do those who claim 33 miracles have.  Compare them.

@Dottard - I just added the list with 33 miracles by John G. Butler.

Here is another list presenting 41 miracles of Jesus: https://theologica.org.uk/the-41-miracles-recorded-in-the-gospels/

@Lesley - The issue with your 41 point list is that some of the miracles mentioned are not directly performed on others, but ambiguous for the narrative, such as "and he healed many others also". The Resurrection is included, but Jesus did not perform that miracle: God the Father raised Jesus from the grave, not Jesus Himself.

According to John 2:19-21 and 10:17, 18, Jesus raised himself from the dead.  But this gets into another question not appropriate here.

@Dottard - nowhere do those passage day that Jesus raised himself from the dead. Only God can raise people from the dead, either alone or through the work of other living vessels.

Did you read john 2 reference - I will raise it (myself, my body) up.  But that is where we differ - I accept the plain statement of the Bible.

@Dottard - Jesus was not saying that He raised Himself, but that the will of God was in Him so He knew with certainly that His Father would raise Him from the dead. https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/verses/john-2-19

Interesting, but that is NOT what the text says.  I take the text over any theory and believe what the text says!

@Dottard, the text does not contradict 1 Corinthians 6:14, which days that God raised Jesus from the dead. Even 1 Peter 1:21 and Acts 2:24 confirm that God the Father raised Jesus from the dead!

@JoshuaB - agreed, the Holy Spirit was also involved - all three raised Jesus from the dead.

@Dottard - Only the Father's Holy Spirit raised Jesus. Jesus did not raise himself!

@JoshuaB - this is not the place for debate.  we should do that in chat.  However, that statement is a circular arguement.

All the lists of miracles posted by the OP are too short.  To these lists we could add others such as:

Jesus exorcised seven demons from Mary Magdalene, Luke 8:2, Mark 16:9
Jesus' bodily ascension (no less a miracle than walking on water), Acts 1:8
Jesus makes Peter walk on water, Matt 14:29, 29
Jesus' own incarnation, Luke 1:26-39, Phil 2:5-8
Jesus' own bodily resurrection, John 2:19-21 and 10:17, 18
Jesus' escape from a murderous mob in Jerusalem, John 8:59
Jesus' escape from a murderous mob in in Capernaum, Luke 4:28-30
Jesus keeps two men from recognizing Him on the road to Emmaus
Jesus vanishes from the two men (above) at dinner
Jesus suddenly appears in the locked upper room on resurrection Sunday
Jesus suddenly appears in the same locked upper room one week later
When Jesus declared Himself the "I Am" to the arresting mob in Gethsemane, they fell backward, John 18:5-8.
etc.

We could go further and include all the miraculous conversions such as the woman at the well, etc.
Further, there are general statements about masses of miracle healings in a number of places such as Matt 4:23, 24, 9:35, 14:14, 35, 36, 15:30, 31, Mark 1:32-34, 3:10, 6:5, Luke 6:17, 18, 4:40, 5:15, 7:21, 8:2, 9:1, John 6:2.

@JoshuaB - I do not know - ask them.

@JoshuaB What significance do you attach to getting the number right?

@Dottard - Your additional entries are not specifically valid, because they are not directly from Jesus upon somebody, or they are accomplished by God to Christ, or they are miraculous events that are not Jesus directly doing something per se, nevertheless supernatural.

@StephenDisraeli - The number 33 is very significant. If Jesus has 33 sets of recorded miracles, it means that God inspired the authors of the Gospels to encode 33 of Christ's many miracles to represent the overcoming of Satan, the god of this world, by symbolically overcoming the Fallen Third (33%) of Satan to redeem mankind through the sacrifice of His Son, which spiritually and physically rescued us the power of the Evil One and his forces.

@JoshuaB - now you are restricting the type of miracles you want on your list which is not part of the original question.  Please define what you want carefully.

@Dottard - I want to know how many muscles Jesus personally performed among others.

@JoshuaB - Jesus performed all His miracles among others, including those you are questioning

@Dottard - All of Jesus' post-resurrection events do not count on these lists, because Jesus was not a flesh and blood human anymore, but returned to being the exulted Angel of God.

That is simply untrue - look at what he said in Luke 24:39 after the resurrection - He had flesh and bone!

@Dottard - Of course Jesus had flesh and bone. Spirit creatures can have bodies of flesh too, but instead of life in the red blood, they have life in the Spirit, light which courses through the veins of the immortal Spiritual Body.

@Dottard - The issue with the reference to Jesus exorcising 7 demons from Mary Magdalene is that the event is not described at all, just mentioned as having happened. Therefore, it does not belong on this specific list, because only live recorded events are being referenced here. Sorry if I did not make that specific in the initial question.

@JoshuaB - so what events do you want - Jesus still did it!

@Dottard - I am looking for specific events which are recorded in live detail, not ones which are mentioned in passing, if you know what I mean.

Then you should define that in the question because that will affect the list significantly.  Jesus' incarnation and resurrection and ascension were all miracles.  His miraculous appearances were also miracles.

Short Answer: It depends on how one counts them.
From what I can tell the most commonly cited number of miracles performed by Jesus that are recorded in the Gospels is 37. However, it is noted that most scholars estimate between 24 and 37. Let me give a few quotes:
According to records from Blue Letter Bible, 37 miracles are recoded.

In the four Gospels, 37 distinct miracles performed by Jesus are
recorded, showcasing His divine authority, His power over nature and
death, and His compassion for the afflicted. [1]


most scholars estimate that Jesus performed between 24 and 37 miracles
that are documented in the gospel accounts. [2]


The four Gospels record 37 miracles of Jesus, with Mark's Gospel
recording the most. [3]


The gospels in the New Testament record 42 miracles Jesus performed
during His short time of ministry. [4]

Yet, christianity.com lists 34 miracles that Jesus performed.
Now, these numbers include various acts of healing, exorcisms, control over nature, and raising people from the dead.
I say this because it’s important to note that the exact number can vary depending on how one defines and counts “miracles.”

John 20:30 NKJV - And truly Jesus did many other signs in the
presence of His disciples, which are not written in this book;

Based on this if we were to include all the signs and healings that Jesus likely performed based on general statements, there could have been hundreds or thousands of miracles overall.
The number can also vary depending on many factors, but each case I believe would have to be taken up with the individual scholar on how they counted and what they would consider a "miracle".
For example, one might count a general statement like, "he healed many people" as one miracle because it occurred during a punctiliar time.
Looking at the first list we see that it counts general statements like:

Jesus Heals Many Sick and Oppressed at Evening
Jesus Heals Many Sick in Gennesaret as They Touch His Garment,

but it also records,

Jesus Heals Two Blind Men

as one miracle rather than two separate miracles.
This is just to point out that depending on how one counts the miracles we could easily calculate a lower or a higher number.

Could it be possible that Jesus did 33 miraculous activities for others?

@JoshuaB Certainly depending on how one counts. For example, in the first list it counts general statements like, 5. Jesus Heals Many Sick and Oppressed at Evening, 21. Jesus Heals Many Sick in Gennesaret as They Touch His Garment,  but it also records, 16. Jesus Heals Two Blind Men as one miracle rather than two separate miracles.

Personally, I think that the healing of the two blind men and the mute man constitute a single miraculous event. It should be called, "The Healing of the Three Men".

My specific question was that are there 33 specifically recorded pre-resurrection miracle events of Jesus in the Gospels? (This is not counting the total number of people affected, or miraculous events that are not clearly specified.)
