Does Matthew 9:32-34, 12:22-24, and Luke 11:14-15 describe the same event where Jesus exorcises a mute and blind demoniac?
Matthew 9:32-34 ESV

As they were going away, behold, a demon-oppressed man who was mute was brought to him. And when the demon had been cast out, the mute man spoke. And the crowds marveled, saying, “Never was anything like this seen in Israel.” But the Pharisees said, “He casts out demons by the prince of demons.”

Matthew 12:22-24 ESV

Then a demon-oppressed man who was blind and mute was brought to him, and he healed him, so that the man spoke and saw. And all the people were amazed, and said, “Can this be the Son of David?” But when the Pharisees heard it, they said, “It is only by Beelzebul, the prince of demons, that this man casts out demons.”

Luke 11:14-15 ESV

Now he was casting out a demon that was mute. When the demon had gone out, the mute man spoke, and the people marveled. But some of them said, “He casts out demons by Beelzebul, the prince of demons.”


If the answer is yes, then that would help answer my other question: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/94355/62615

It is understandable why the original poster would inquire about the possibility that Matthew 9:32-34, Matthew 12:22-24 and Luke 11:14-15 all refer to the same account.



Matthew 9:32-34
Matthew 12:22-24
Luke 11:14-15




healed a mute man possessed by demon

healed a mute man possessed by demon



healed a blind and mute man possessed by demon



The Pharisees commented that Jesus drove out demons by the prince of demons (Matt 9:34)
The Pharisses commented that Jesus drove out demons by the prince of demons (Matt 12:24)
Someone commented that Jesus drove out demons by the prince of demons (Luke 11:15)



Jesus rebuked the comment immediately afterward (Matt 12:25-30)
Jesus rebuked the comment immediately afterward (Luke 11:16-23)



If we compare the elements of these three accounts, it certainly gives the impression that they are likely to be the same account. Before we delve into the analysis, let's review a parrallel account in Mark3:20-27

20 Then Jesus entered a house, and again a crowd gathered, so that he and his disciples were not even able to eat. 21 When his family heard about this, they went to take charge of him, for they said, “He is out of his mind.”
22 And the teachers of the law who came down from Jerusalem said, “He is possessed by Beelzebul! By the prince of demons he is driving out demons.”
23 So Jesus called them over to him and began to speak to them in parables: “How can Satan drive out Satan? 24 If a kingdom is divided against itself, that kingdom cannot stand. 25 If a house is divided against itself, that house cannot stand. 26 And if Satan opposes himself and is divided, he cannot stand; his end has come. 27 In fact, no one can enter a strong man’s house without first tying him up. Then he can plunder the strong man’s house.

Mark does not explicitly state why Jesus and His disciples were so busy that they had to skip eating. However, it is likely that Jesus was occupied with healing a large crowd of people. Therefore, it would not be surprising if, within the crowd, there were both a blind man and a blind and mute man.
Since none of the Synoptic Gospels was written in strict chronological order, it may not be crucial to affirm that they are the same account. The teachings from the Synoptic Gospels emphasize Jesus' compassion for humanity despite the opposition He faced.

It may not be crucial to affirm, but for me this is important to uncover because it would confirm that Jesus has 33 recorded miracle sets before his resurrection, which unlocks a numerological connection with the years of Jesus life (33), and much more surrounding the number 33.

@JoshuaB - Although John's gospel recounts that Jesus had performed many signs (John 20:30) , he chooses to highlight only seven. The eighth miracle in chapter 21 has the possibility of additional content being added later. John as a Jew, appears to adhere to the symbolic number 7. However, the deliberate arrangement of 33 miracle sets across four gospels and any symbolic meaning behind this distribution remain unclear. The reasoning of this arrangement is elusive and likely controversial.

That's the best answer I could get. Thank you and God bless your efforts.

@JoshuaB - try my best. Thank you!

In short, you think it is possible that all three events are of a single event?

@JoshuaB - it is possible, but not definite.
